# Подключить WindowsAzureMessaging.framework для iOS в Qt проект?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt

Qt проект для Android и iOs
Нужно подключить [WindowsAzureMessaging.framework] библиотеку в iOs сборку для работы с пуш-сообщениями.

Коды примера использования библиотеки от Azure [здесь](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/)
Там же [ссылка на библиотеку](http://aka.ms/kymw2g)

Пока собрать проект с библиотекой не получается.

В файле qt-проекта прописал следующее:

```
include($${MODULES_DIR}/common/platform/mac/WindowsAzureMessaging/platform_mac_windowsazuremessaging.pri)
QMAKE_LFLAGS += $${MODULES_DIR}/common/platform/mac/
LIBS += -framework WindowsAzureMessaging
```

файла platform_mac_windowsazuremessaging.pri в исходной библиотеке нет. У меня он такой:

```
isEmpty(ONCE_INCLUDED_CORE_MODULES_PLATFORM_MAC_WINDOWSAZUREMESSAGING_PRI) {
        ONCE_INCLUDED_CORE_MODULES_PLATFORM_MAC_WINDOWSAZUREMESSAGING_PRI = 1
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
LIBS += -framework WindowsAzureMessaging
HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBConnectionString.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBLocalStorage.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBNotificationHub.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBRegistration.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBStoredRegistrationEntry.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/SBTokenProvider.h \
    $$PWD/Headers/WindowsAzureMessaging.h
}
```

Подключение заголовка из библиотеки в iosappdelegate.h:

```
#import <WindowsAzureMessaging/Headers/WindowsAzureMessaging.h>
...
```

Ошибка при сборке проекта

```
/Users/admin/XXX/apps/XXX/src/application/iosappdelegate.h:4: ошибка: 'WindowsAzureMessaging/Headers/WindowsAzureMessaging.h' file not found
#import <WindowsAzureMessaging/Headers/WindowsAzureMessaging.h>
        ^

CompileC XXX.build/Release-iphoneos/XXX.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iosappdelegate.o /Users/admin/XXX/apps/XXX/src/application/iosappdelegate.mm normal armv7 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/admin/build-XXX-iphoneos_clang_Qt_5_5_1_for_iOS-Release/apps/XXX
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot
```

Помогите советом )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ был найден [здесь](http://forum.qt.io/topic/40375/solved-can-t-add-ios-opencv-framework-in-a-qt-project)

```
LIBS += \
     -F $${MODULES_DIR}/common/platform/mac \
     -framework WindowsAzureMessaging
```